# Trying to change administrator password

Tags: 11.10

I have tryed to change the password with the information that jorge castro has
put up. when i get to the UNIX password change it says (Authentication token manipulation error) then says password unchanged. is there another way to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu ;)

open up the terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and then write:

```
passwd
```

hit enter. it will ask your current and the new desired password ;)

hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you have posted, it sounds like you are attempting to change a user password from the root shell of the recovery console, and have missed the step of remounting the filesystem in read-write mode i.e.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

before doing

```
passwd <username>
```

It would be easier to answer your question definitively if you had posted the actual steps you have taken - rather then just "with the information that jorge castro has put up".